# Does this proposition from complex analysis depend on AC?

Tags: complex-analysis, axiom-of-choice

I was reading III vol. of Princeton lectures on analysis. Proposition 1.4:
"If $\Omega_{1}\supset\Omega_{2}\supset\ldots\supset\Omega_{n}\supset\ldots $ is a sequence of non-empty
compact sets in $\Bbb C$ with the property that:

$$\operatorname{diam}(\Omega_{n})\to 0\text{ as } n\to\infty,$$

then there exists a unique point $w\in\Bbb C$ such that $w \in \Omega_{n}$ for all $n$."

And in the proof:"Choose point $z_{n}$ in each $\Omega_{n}$"
Apparently this proof relies on Axiom of Choice. But I'm interested if it can be proved without reference to AC?

Comment: Existence might require AC, but uniqueness certainly doesn't.

Comment: What is $C$? Is it the complex numbers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fortunately, the axiom of choice can be circumvented here.

$\Bbb C$ is a Polish space, namely it is separable and completely metrizable. Moreover we are talking about *compact* sets and not *sequentially compact sets*. The equivalence between the two notion does require the axiom of choice, but it's not used here.

Now. Compact sets are closed in $\Bbb C$. And as luck would have it, we can choose from compact sets uniformly in $\Bbb C$, without using the axiom of choice. To see why, fix a countable dense subset $\{d_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$, and for each non-empty compact $E$ set define a sequence by induction, $x_n=d_k$ if either $k$ is the least for which $d_k\in E$, or else if it is the least index such that $\frac12d(x_{n-1},E)>d(d_k,E)$ (for $n=0$ take $d_0$).

This sequence is Cauchy, therefore it converges, and it converges to a unique point whose distance from $E$ is $0$. By compactness it means that the limit is in $E$.

In this definition we didn't use the axiom of choice because $\{d_k\mid k\in\Bbb N\}$ is a countable set.

Therefore, choosing from each $\Omega_n$ is possible even without assuming the axiom of choice holds.

Comment: Note, by the way, that this argument is not hinged on the family of compact sets being countable; and in fact we can push it to arbitrary non-empty closed sets.

Comment: Did you mean $ d(d_k,E)<\frac12d(x_{n-1},E)$?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: I'd be interested to hear about the downvote.

Answer (score 14):

As Asaf says, Choice is not needed. Another way to see it.

Note that if $\bigcap_n \Omega_n = \varnothing$, then $\{ \mathbb C \setminus \Omega_n : n \in \mathbb N \}$ is a family of open subsets of $\mathbb C$ which covers $\Omega_1$. However no finite subfamily of this covers $\Omega_1$:  if $n_1 < \ldots < n_k$ then $$( \mathbb C \setminus \Omega_{n_1} ) \cup \cdots \cup ( \mathbb C \setminus \Omega_{n_k} ) = \mathbb C \setminus ( \Omega_{n_1} \cap \cdots \cap \Omega_{n_k} ) = \mathbb C \setminus \Omega_{n_k},$$ and $\Omega_{n_k}$ is a nonempty subset of $\Omega_1$, contradicting the compactness of $\Omega_1$.  This is a purely topological argument.

That $\bigcap_n \Omega_n$ contains a single point can be seen by supposing that $z \neq z^\prime$ are both in $\bigcap_n \Omega_n$, and taking an $n$ such that $\operatorname{diam} \Omega_n < | z - z^\prime |$.

Comment: Very nice.${}{}$

Answer (score 3):

Let $K\subset\mathbb {C}$ be compact. Let $a=\inf \{x: (x,y)\in K\}.$ Then set $b = \inf \{y: (a,y) \in K\}.$ Exercise: Show $(a,b)\in K.$ We can think of $(a,b)$ as the "southern-most eastern-most point" of $K.$ In fact, let's denote this point by $SEP(K).$ That solves our choosing problem: Given any family $\{K_\alpha\}$ of nonempty compact subsets of $\mathbb C,$ we simply choose, for each $\alpha,$ $SEP(K_\alpha).$

Comment: Exactly. This is what makes the real numbers so tame.